# Cygwin and PuTTYCyg /bin/sh: No such file or directory

Tags: cygwin, reset

Somehow I messed up my cygwin install so i cannot use PuTTycyg to connect to it. I get this error:`/bin/sh: No such file or directory` What could I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be a conflict between the cygwin1.dll file supplied with PuTTycyg and Cygwin's own cygwin1.dll file. You can try copying the cygwin1.dll file from c:\cygwin\bin\ to the folder where you have placed PuTTyCyg.